# How to interpret the given Well Formed Formula?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

How to interpret the first order logic given by :-

$$∀x∀yP(x,y)→∀x∀yP(y,x)$$

---

I can see that this is not a logical implication .

LHS can be interpreted as : (Just assuming)

Take Domain : ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7}$ and $P(x,y) = x<y$

So, $P(1,2) = P(3,7)$ is true and this make $RHS$ false.

---

But, How to read it.

Is this like $$∀x∀y(P(x,y)→∀x∀yP(y,x))$$ OR

$$(∀x∀yP(x,y))→(∀x∀yP(y,x))$$

What is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 1):

The second interpretation is what it should be. Without parentheses the scope of the quantifier is always just the formula right after it.

Also, as a general equivalence principle we have:

**Swapping Quantifiers of Same Type**

For any formula $\varphi$:

$\forall x \forall y \ \varphi \Leftrightarrow \forall y \forall x \ \varphi$

$\exists x \exists y \ \varphi \Leftrightarrow \exists y \exists x \ \varphi$

(That is: you can always swap two quantifiers of the same type that are right next to each other and retain equivalence)

So, since the LHS and RHS of your conditional are equivalent, your statement *is* a logical truth.

THe first interpretation (which again, is *not* how you should read the original conditional) says: As soon as for any $x$ and $y$ we have $P(x,y)$, then $P(x,y)$ holds for all $x$ and $y$ (indeed, it is equivalent to $\exists x \exists y \rightarrow \forall x \forall y P(x,y)$) ... which is clearly not a logical truth. USing your interpretation: just because there are *some* $x$ and $y$ with $x<y$ does not mean that $x<y$ for *all* $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It is not quite as simple as that, because there _are_ traditions where $\to$ binds tighter than $\forall$ -- especially ones influenced by lambda cakculus and type theory. I agree that in this case the author _most probably_ meant $(∀x∀yP(x,y))→(∀x∀yP(y,x))$, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm OK, good to know!  I have never encountered those, but I haven't really ever dealt with lambda calculus either. Thanks for the heads up!